# stringByAppendingFormat not working

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-concatenation

I have an NSString and fail to apply the following statement:

```
NSString *myString = @"some text";
[myString stringByAppendingFormat:@"some text = %d", 3];
```

no log or error, the string just doesn't get changed. I already tried with NSString (as documented) and NSMutableString.

any clues most welcome.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I would suggest correcting to ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingFormat:)):

```
NSString *myString = @"some text";
myString = [myString stringByAppendingFormat:@" = %d", 3];
```

From the docs:

> Returns a string made by appending to the receiver a string constructed from a given format string and the following arguments.

Answer (score 12):

It's working, you're just ignoring the return value, which is the string with the appended format. (See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingFormat:).) You can't modify an NSString — to modify an NSMutableString, use [-appendFormat:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendFormat:) instead.

Of course, in your toy example, you could shorten it to this:

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"some text = %d", 3];
```

However, it's likely that you need to append a format string to an existing string created elsewhere. In that case, and particularly if you're appending multiple parts, it's good to think about and balance the pros and cons of using a mutable string or several immutable, autoreleased strings.

Answer (score 11):

Creating strings with `@""` always results in immutable strings. If you want to create a new NSMutableString do it as following.

```
NSMutableString *myString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"some text"];
[myString appendFormat:@"some text = %d", 3];
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar warning message while appending a localized string. This is how I resolved it

```
NSString *msgBody = [msgBody stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",NSLocalizedString(@"LOCALSTRINGMSG",@"Message Body")];
```

Comment: Unless you really have got a format to append, it's better to use -stringByAppendingString: instead.